# setup:upgrade error for query

Tags: magento2.3

I have updated **magento** from 2.2.7 to 2.3.1 and I get a `setup:upgrade` error but have no idea where to look.

The error is for the following query:

> SHOW INDEXES FROM catalog_category_product_2.0.7 WHERE `Non_unique` =
>   1

There is an error because the table has no quotes and the version 2.0.7 is not valid.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1: Added a screenshot**

[image]

**Update 2: Not quoted**

It looks like that in the following file the with readIndexes the $tableName is not quoted. Not any of the functions the tablename is quoted and the errors continue.

> vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/MySQL/DbSchemaReader.php

Comment: what instructions did you follow? 2.2.X to 2.3.X is not just a composer version increase and then "setup:upgrade"...

Comment: Check your module version and upgrade it.

Comment: I had followed an instruction I had to update the composer psr4 version. Also updated most of the composer modules. But this error does not say which module produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error screenshot, it seems that some of the custom extension have fired custom sql query as

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM catalog_category_product_2.0.7 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1
```

Actually the table name contains .(dot) so the query should be as below.

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM `catalog_category_product_2.0.7` WHERE `Non_unique` = 1
```

Try to find out the module which fires this query and make the changes.

Comment: Yes I know this is why there is an error. I now have updated the vendor/magento file where the SHOW INDEXES query is executed and added the '`' on every table query. But is a very bad solution