# Strange error when upgrading

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, database-schema

when trying to run setup:upgrade i'm getting the error below.
I dont remember having any issues on my store.
I've tried to enable verbose on the upgrade using setup:upgrade -vv but wiithout success

Below is the error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't_scope1_tmp WHERE 
`Non_unique` = 1' at line 2, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp WHERE `Non_unique` = 1

Can anyone help me please.

Regards

Comment: restart the mysql after check..

Comment: i've restarted the mysql, but the error remains.

Comment: SHOW INDEXES FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp WHERE Non_unique = 1 run query

Comment: what showing share me

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268366/setupupgrade-error-for-query

Comment: it says that the table does not exist...but thats not the strangest part...seems that there are a lot of whitespaces on the query between catalogsearch_fulltex and tscope1_tmp...

Comment: you checked above link ???

Comment: yes..but the issue is on a \n and the table dont exist...i cannot pinpoint the script that is causing this. (i've changed the DbSchemaReader.php to remove the \n and still get the table error)

Comment: you which query run ??

Comment: try this SHOW INDEXES FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 WHERE Non_unique = 1 this query tmp text removed after check

Comment: i've managed to solve this...changing the DbSchemaReader to avoid this table and the \n